# device_util not found in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to import `device_util` using:

```
from tensorflow.python.distribute import device_util
```

However `device_util` isn't found. The version is tensorflow-gpu 1.12.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been moved recently.

Try under `training` for release 1.12.0:

```
from tensorflow.python.training import device_util
```

Source code: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/training/device_util.py

Comment: Thanks! I've searched the [release notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases) before asking, but haven't seen any reference.